# Without recursive CTE use how to get below expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Without recursive CTE use how to get below expected result..

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
      ParentCode VARCHAR (100)
    , ChildCode VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT '101', '102' UNION ALL 
SELECT '102', '101' UNION ALL 
SELECT '103', '104' UNION ALL 
SELECT '104', '103' UNION ALL 
SELECT '105', '106' UNION ALL 
SELECT '106', '105'

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Output:

```
ParentCode 
101
103
105
```

Comment: Why is a recursive CTE not acceptable? The answer to that may effect what other answers may or may not work and/or be acceptable to you.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the expected result.

Comment: Also, please indicate (via tags) what database system (and version) you're using. I would probably guess at SQL Server.

Comment: Is it, `SELECT ParentCode As ParentCode FROM @temp WHERE CAST((ParentCode) AS int) % 2 != 0`

Comment: Have you already got a recursive CTE solution? You could add it to your question so that we could try deriving the logic of the expected output from it (in case it is difficult for you to explain the logic in English).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
      ParentCode VARCHAR (100)
    , ChildCode VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT '101', '102' UNION ALL 
SELECT '102', '101' UNION ALL 
SELECT '103', '104' UNION ALL 
SELECT '104', '103' UNION ALL 
SELECT '105', '106' UNION ALL 
SELECT '106', '105'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ParentCode
        , ChildCode
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ParentCode, ChildCode)
    FROM @temp 
)    
SELECT t.ParentCode 
FROM cte t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM cte t2 
    WHERE t.ParentCode = t2.ChildCode
        AND t.rn < t2.rn
)
```

**Output:**

```
ParentCode
----------
101
103
105
```